# What are some Linux-compatible MATLAB substitutes?

Tags: linux, matlab

It seems you need a license to use MATLAB. I do not have one so I was wondering if there was some highly-compatible substitute for it in Linux.

Comment: In principle you have just as much need of a license to use Open Source or Free software. You just get one automatically and *gratis*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [R](https://www.r-project.org/)
- [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)/ [KOctive (GUI)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/koctave/).
- [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/)
- [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/)
- [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)

I'm not sure if these are applicable without knowing what you're trying to achieve.

Sadly, you won't get anything as powerful as Matlab without paying up.

Comment: Eh?  Surely you just mean Scilab, rather than "Matlab to Scilab translator"; TeXmacs is a document creator not a MATLAB alternative; Sage is more for pure maths than linear algrebra.  Also, you missed R.

Answer (score 9):

[GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) has "a language that is mostly compatible with MATLAB".  They also have [a section in their FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/FAQ.html#MATLAB-compatibility) about MATLAB compatibility that covers pretty much all the difficulties/differences between the two.

Depending on what exactly you need to do:

- [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is good for basic-intermediate graphing
- [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) (using Python) is also good for graphing
- [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) is a computer algebra system

Answer (score 3):

Again depending on what exactly you need to do

- [R](http://www.r-project.org/) - a free software environment for statistical computing and graphics.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), an open source Matlab-like program. Don't know how compatible it is with the 'real' Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)
2. [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/)
3. [Python](http://python.org/) + [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) + [MatPlotLib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Besides Octave, check also:
**Pari/GP**
http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html